# Tkinter GUI occasionally opens halfway but a modifier key press keeps it going?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, ubuntu-18.04

I'm developing a couple of GUIs (28 and 267 kB so far) with Tkinter and Python2.7 on Ubuntu 18.04, and when pulling them onto machines other than my own, they sometimes (50% of the time) soft-fail on start-up from the Terminal. The GUI will partially open (window appears but no or few widgets) and freeze at that point.

This freezing is thawed when I press any of Shift, Control, Alt (either side of the keyboard), Num Lock, Caps Lock, or the Windows key. The GUI carries on loading and functions as expected but the problem will occasionally arise whenever a new window is generated from inside the GUI. The machines I'm experiencing this on all appear to have the same set-up of Software and OS.

Does anyone know about this quirk of Tkinter?

EDIT: Mildly reproducible source code

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import Tkinter as Tk


class TestProgram:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.top = parent
        self.top.after(1000, self.top.destroy)

root = Tk.Tk()
GUI_obj = TestProgram(parent=root)
root.mainloop()
```

Annoyingly when scraping this down to barebones the semi-freeze occurs once out of several dozen attempts to start it from the terminal with **./TestProgram**.

I had a look at the System Monitor while it freezes, the status switches from Running to Sleeping a few seconds after it freezes, and pressing one of the keys switches it back to Running before going to Sleep once everything has loaded in.

EDIT 2: Took out even more code from the example, found it a lot easier to just run the program on a loop for 100 iterations and wait for it to freeze.

EDIT 3: I've discovered that running the code as **sudo ./TestProgram** eliminates the bug entirely, but I still can't find out why or what is changing between executions. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is something that will be very hard to troubleshoot. Can you provide some code example that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: ***"other than my own"***: You probably use Python 2.7 only statements. The *others* may using Python 3.x.

Comment: Are you using threading? I don't think we'll be able to help without a [mcve].

Comment: @stovfl - All machines are set up with the same versions of the software.

Comment: @BryanOakley  Threading is imported and in use, but not during the start-up or functions that experience this semi-freezing. I'll try and get a reproducible example from the smaller of my two problem-GUIs. In the morning.

Comment: _"Threading is imported and in use, but not during the start-up or functions that experience this semi-freezing"_ - are you _absolutely_ certain of that? I see people get threading code wrong quite often, and the behavior you describe sounds like it could be caused by threading issues.

Comment: @BryanOakley I've taken a version of the GUI and removed as much as I could while still experiencing the bug (at a much reduced rate now). The reduced code is in my edit now.

Comment: @BryanOakley - I've found that running the code with sudo stops the problem entirely, any thoughts as to why or what might've changed with that?